# Implementing a thread safe data structure with kotlin coroutines

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to implement a thread safe key-value disk store with coroutines. The store should be able to process put and get requests in FCFS order. When going through the documentation, I found this [article](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html) on shared mutable state and concurrency and came across the actor coroutine builder.

The example on the doc illustrates how a counter variable can be incremented safely from parallel coroutines.

Assuming that the actor builder would be well suited, I tried using the same construct to update an integer variable with some predefined set of values in parallel. However, sending a get message to the actor after executing all updates does not return the expected last-updated value.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `updating actor state from multiple coroutines should hold the last updated value`() = runBlocking {

        val counter = actor<CounterMsg> {
            var counter = 0 // actor state
            for (msg in channel) { // iterate over incoming messages
                when (msg) {
                    is GetCounter -> msg.response.complete(counter)
                    is SetCounter -> counter = msg.value
                }
            }
        }
        val numbers = arrayOf(1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 10)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            numbers.forEach {
                launch {
                    counter.send(SetCounter(it))
                }
            }
        }
        // send a message to get a counter value from an actor
        val response = CompletableDeferred<Int>()
        counter.send(GetCounter(response))
        val actualValue = response.await()
        counter.close() // shutdown the actor
        assertEquals(numbers.last(), actualValue) //fails, expected to get 10
    }

    // Message types for counterActor
    sealed class CounterMsg
    class GetCounter(val response: CompletableDeferred<Int>) : CounterMsg() // a request with reply
    class SetCounter(val value: Int) : CounterMsg()
```

I understand that the test is failing as the order of execution is not guaranteed with launch, async or any suspend function.

But users may call 'get' or 'put' with the said constructs and expect
to read the last value that they had updated.

How do I update the integer in a specific order and make sure that it always holds the last updated value?

Comment: I think he problem  comes from the use of launch. It submits async tasks. There's no guarantee that they will be treated in order, as they're launched concurrently.

Comment: Answering after your edit. The thing is: your code already guarantees that the actor holds the last updated value. You just don't know which is the last value. In real world it usually doesn't make too much sense to execute two concurrent operations that sets the same value at the end, because results of one of them will be overridden by the second and you don't even know which will finish last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An FCFS store can indeed be implemented with the actor builder. My approach of testing the ordering was wrong. Ordering cannot be guaranteed in launch, async or after invoking any suspend function (including suspending on actor responses with CompletableDeferred). Here's a better test for a concurrent queue with actor - This test asserts that concurrently polling from the actor based queue returns the head elements in offered order.

```kotlin
    @RepeatedTest(5)
    fun `actor queue test`() = runTest {

        val sendQueue = LinkedList<Int>()
        val receiveQueue = ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Int>()

        val queueActor = actor<QueueMsg>(capacity = Channel.UNLIMITED) {
            val queue = LinkedList<Int>()
            for (msg in channel) {
                when (msg) {
                    is OfferQueue -> run {
                        queue.offer(msg.value)
                        sendQueue.offer(msg.value)
                    }
                    is PollQueue -> run {
                        val polledInt = queue.poll()
                        msg.response.complete(polledInt)
                        receiveQueue.offer(polledInt)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            repeat(10) {
                launch {
                    queueActor.trySend(OfferQueue(it))
                }
            }
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            repeat(10) {
                launch {
                    val response = CompletableDeferred<Int>()
                    queueActor.trySend(PollQueue(response))
                }
            }
        }
        queueActor.close()
        assertIterableEquals(sendQueue, receiveQueue)
    }

    // Message types for queueActor
    sealed class QueueMsg
    class PollQueue(val response: CompletableDeferred<Int>) : QueueMsg() // a request with reply
    class OfferQueue(val value: Int) : QueueMsg()
```

There is no way to update the state of an actor in a specific order from multiple coroutines unless one uses a single threaded dispatcher. However, it is guaranteed that the actor will update its state in the order that it receives the update.

Similarly, there is no guarantee on the actor response ordering when the responses are collected by awaiting on deferred(s).

For a FCFS store, all operations can be processed in order by sending them through an actor and ensuring that no other suspend functions are invoked within the operations themselves.